# D3 initial zoom from v3 to v4 and v5

Tags: d3.js, zooming, scale

I'm using d3 v3 code to achieve initial zoom scale on the timeline graph by doing so :

```
var xAxis = d3.axisTop(x)
        .ticks(3)
        .tickPadding(30)
        .tickSizeOuter(0)
        .tickFormat(function (d, i) {
          return i === 0 ? 'Deadline 1' : i === 1 ? 'Deadline 2' : 'Deadline ' + d3.timeFormat('%d %b')(new Date(maxDt))
        }
        )
var x = d3.scaleTime().domain([minDt, maxDt]).range([groupWidth, width]);
var zoom = d3.zoom().x(x).on('zoom', zoomed).scaleExtent(.68);
```

and my zoomed function is as follow

```
function zoomed() {
        if (self.onVizChangeFn && d3.event) {
            self.onVizChangeFn.call(self, {
                scale: d3.event.scale,
                translate: d3.event.translate,
                domain: x.domain()
            });
        }

        svg
          .select('.x.axis')
          .call(xAxis)

        svg
          .selectAll('circle.dot')
          .attr('cx', (d) => x(d.at))
      }
    }
```

However, function .x(x) doesn't work on v4 or v5 versions of D3. Is there an alternative that I could use in

```
var zoom = d3.zoom().x(x).on('zoom', zoomed).scaleExtent(.68);
```

to be able to set initial zoom level?